# Symfony 3 composer, ext-dom and ext-xml missing

Tags: symfony, phpunit, composer-php

I am running Linux Mint 18.1. My IDE is PhpStorm and I am trying to install PHPUnit trough the composer. I followed the installation steps at https://getcomposer.org/download/.

> Problem 1
>       - Installation request for phpunit/phpunit 6.4.x-dev -> satisfiable by phpunit/phpunit[6.4.x-dev].
>       - phpunit/phpunit 6.4.x-dev requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
>   Problem 2
>       - symfony/symfony v3.3.6 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
>       - symfony/symfony v3.3.6 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
>       - symfony/symfony v3.3.6 requires ext-xml * -> the requested PHP extension xml is missing from your system.
>       - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.3.6, required as 3.3.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.6].

Solutions I have tried:

- Install php-xml
- Install php7.0-xml
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37873482/laravel-composer-update-the-requested-php-extension-dom-is-missing-from-your-s) says to check if "extension=dom.so" is enabled in any of your php.ini files. It is not even present in my files

Any suggestions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 32):

All you need to install from your terminal in Debian is:

```
sudo apt-get install php-xml
```

Or, if you're using PHP 7:

```
 sudo apt-get install php7.0-xml
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response but one of the first things I did was check if those were installed and they are, and updated to the latest version.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php-mbstring  "i guess you are missing mbstring"  than composer update "update your composer "

Comment: Also have php-mbstring installed. Composer was always the latest version.

Comment: It turns out there was something off with my composer installation. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45585073/phpunit-working-in-ide-but-server-says-class-not-found) for if you want to know how I fixed this.

Comment: good for you , i m glad you fixed your issue .

Comment: It worked for me. But it'd probably not work for someone else (pretty much everybody else), so -1.

Comment: For php 7.2 you can use `sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml` to install the correct version .. i think this works too with 7.1

Comment: Of course, for php 7.3 : `sudo apt-get install php7.3-xml` :)