# When I use Symfony and create a file in Controller I get the error Logic Exception Extension DOM is required

Tags: php, symfony

I installed the Symfony skeleton and I am running with the integrated development server. I am using Ubuntu.

When I go to src/Controller and create the file ArticleController.php I get the error `LogicException` `Extension DOM is required.`

I even tried to install PHP-XML and my system shows that it is already installed.

This is the output that I get

`in XmlUtils.php line 50
at XmlUtils::parse('<?xml version="1.0" ?><container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services https://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd"> <services> <defaults public="false" /> <service id="controller_name_converter" class="Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\ControllerNameParser"> <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="request" /> <argument type="service" id="kernel" /> </service> <service id="controller_resolver" class="Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\Controller\\ControllerResolver"> <tag name="monolog.logger" channel="request" /> <argument type="service" id="service_container" /> <argument type="service" id="controller_name_converter" /> <argument type="service" id="logger" on-invalid="ignore" /> </service> <service id="argument_metadata_factory" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\ControllerMetadata\\ArgumentMetadataFactory" /> <service id="argument_resolver" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver"> <argument type="service" id="argument_metadata_factory" /> <argument /> <!-- argument value resolvers --> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.request_attribute" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\RequestAttributeValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="100" /> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.request" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\RequestValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="50" /> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.session" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\SessionValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="50" /> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.service" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\ServiceValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="-50" /> <argument /> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.default" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\DefaultValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="-100" /> </service> <service id="argument_resolver.variadic" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Controller\\ArgumentResolver\\VariadicValueResolver"> <tag name="controller.argument_value_resolver" priority="-150" /> </service> <service id="response_listener" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ResponseListener"> <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" /> <argument>%kernel.charset%</argument> </service> <service id="streamed_response_listener" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\StreamedResponseListener"> <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" /> </service> <service id="locale_listener" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\LocaleListener"> <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" /> <argument type="service" id="request_stack" /> <argument>%kernel.default_locale%</argument> <argument type="service" id="router" on-invalid="ignore" /> </service> <service id="http_exception_listener" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ExceptionListener"> <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="kernel.exception" method="onKernelException" priority="-2048" /> <tag name="kernel.reset" method="reset" /> <argument>null</argument> <argument>null</argument> <argument>%kernel.debug%</argument> <argument>%kernel.charset%</argument> <argument>%debug.file_link_format%</argument> </service> <service id="validate_request_listener" class="Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\EventListener\\ValidateRequestListener"> <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" /> </service> <service id="resolve_controller_name_subscriber" class="Symfony\\Bundle\\FrameworkBundle\\EventListener\\ResolveControllerNameSubscriber"> <argument type="service" id="controller_name_converter" /> <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber" /> </service> </services></container>', array(object(XmlFileLoader), 'validateSchema'))
in XmlUtils.php line 131`

I am trying to learn Symfony and was taking a course from YouTube to learn how it works. So I am a newbie with Symfony. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you try `composer require ext-dom`?

Comment: That did the trick! Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45593729/symfony-3-composer-ext-dom-and-ext-xml-missing

Answer (score 0):

For some reason I only get this error when I run the symfony app via the integrated server it comes with. But when I run it from my LAMPP stack, and I place the symfony application within my Apache, the error goes away.

I am not sure why that is happening, but I guess I will just use it like this.

For some reason I only get this error when I run the symfony app via the integrated server it comes with. But when I run it from my LAMPP stack, and I place the symfony application within my Apache, the error goes away.

I am not sure why that is happening, but I guess I will just use it like this.

EDIT:

`composer require ext-dom` within the project folder did the trick!

Farhang gave me the solution. I appreciate it.